# Undefined command: "layout" when I run gdb on Window 10

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb, wsl-2

I was debugging using gdb in VScode but then I came across with a situation where I need to show the memory addresses.
Since it is not available to do that on VScode I tried to use gdb on windows but I could not run tui.
`Undefined command: "layout"` came out when I type `layout next`
I tried to use WSL-2 and it worked fine and tui opens correctly but another issue came out.
When I type the command `break 1` the following message shows

```
warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x404074
```

and the breaking point does not work.
Are there any suggestion for this problem?
I care about showing memory addresses while debugging c++ code so if there any solution to workaround I am glad to hear it.

Comment: Adding the tag ```windows``` may help you find a better audience.

Comment: So you have 2 different gdb versions? It looks like you windows gdb was built without TUI support. Is your application 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: @ssbssa I have tried to reinstall gdb on windows.
the application is 64bit